# how can i add a view like textview from another layout to current layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a layout form Programmatically . for this for example i want to add a view like textview in my form a couple of times . i created another layout that has a textview now i want to add this textview a couple of times in my current layout .

```
public class FileForm extends Activity {

    LinearLayout LIN_Main;
    TextView TV_GroupTitle;
    LayoutInflater LYOTInf;
    View VIW_AllItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_form);
        LIN_Main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LIN_Main);
        LYOTInf = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        VIW_AllItems = LYOTInf.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
        TV_GroupTitle = (TextView) VIW_AllItems.findViewById(R.id.TV_GroupTitle); 
        int INT_GroupNum = 0;
        List<Integer> INT_EmNumInGroup = new ArrayList<Integer>();;
        EmManager EMM = null;
        EMM = EMM.getInstance();    

        Element EmNode = EMM.getEm();
        Element  EmG = null;
        Element  EmE = null;
        NodeList Group = null;
        NodeList EmList = null;
        Group = EmNode.getChildNodes();
        INT_GroupNum = Group.getLength();
        LIN_Main.removeAllViews();

        for (int i=0;i<INT_GroupNum;i++)
        {
            EmList = Group.item(i).getChildNodes();
            INT_EmNumInGroup.add(EmList.getLength());

            for (int j=0;j<INT_EmNumInGroup.get(i);j++)
            {
                EmE = (Element) EmList.item(j);
                for(int att=0;att<Integer.parseInt(EmE.getAttribute("Num"));att++)
                {
                    TV_GroupTitle.setText(EmE.getNodeName());
                    LIN_Main.addView(TV_GroupTitle);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.file_form, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

but there is error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must to create the TextView programmatically (TextView text = new TextView(context)), not with the findviewById and you must do it in the for, like this:

```
    for (int j=0;j<INT_EmNumInGroup.get(i);j++)
            {

                EmE = (Element) EmList.item(j);

                for(int att=0;att<Integer.parseInt(EmE.getAttribute("Num"));att++)
                {

                    TextView TV_GroupTitle = new TextView(this)

                    TV_GroupTitle.setText(EmE.getNodeName());

                    LIN_Main.addView(TV_GroupTitle);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either inflate the layout as often as you need it

```
for(int att=0;att<Integer.parseInt(EmE.getAttribute("Num"));att++) {
    TextView textView = (TextView)LYOTInf.inflate(R.layout.item,null);
    LIN_Main.addView(textView);
}
```

or just create new TextView objects programmatically

```
for(int att=0;att<Integer.parseInt(EmE.getAttribute("Num"));att++) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    //Configure the textView here (LayoutParams, ...)
    LIN_Main.addView(textView);
}
```

Just make sure that you have a new object for every row! You can't just set the text on the same object and add it again (like you did)

```
for(int att=0;att<Integer.parseInt(EmE.getAttribute("Num"));att++)
{
     TV_GroupTitle.setText(EmE.getNodeName());
     LIN_Main.addView(TV_GroupTitle);
}
```

Comment: yes you are right . in ListView , its possible to add a textview from a layout a couple times in each row of listview . in this case can i do this